# I2C and softwareserial

Tags: i2c, softwareserial, gps

Attempting to make gps unit with screen. GPS unit communicates over serial (Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout) and I can get GPS data through USB to my pc with Adafruit GPS library softwareserial examples. The screen communicates over I2C (Sunfounder OLED-SSD1306 Module) and I can get display with Adafruit SSD1306 examples. However I cannot get both to happen simultaneously. Board is Adafruit Metro Mini 5v 16MHZ. GPS is using pin 8 for TX and pin 9 for RX. Display is using A4 for SDA and A5 for SCL.

If "Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);" is not commented the screen will not display anything. If it is commented the screen displays just fine. How do I get both to function simultaneously?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#define OLED_RESET     -1
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET); 
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9);
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

void setup() {
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { 
    for(;;);
  }
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, SSD1306_WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  testdrawchar();
}


void loop() {
}

void testdrawchar(void) {
  display.clearDisplay();

  display.setTextSize(1);  
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE); 
  display.setCursor(0, 0);    
  display.cp437(true);  

  for(int16_t i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if(i == '\n') display.write(' ');
    else          display.write(i);
  }

  display.display();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: I guess, you run out of memory

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed running out of memory (as suggested by Juraj). After finding smaller libraries I was able to get it to work together just fine.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. What libraries were chosen?

Comment: Final list of libraries:  
`#include <AltSoftSerial.h>  
#include <TinyGPS.h>  
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
#include "SSD1306Ascii.h"  
#include "SSD1306AsciiAvrI2c.h"  
#include <Wire.h>`  
  
All of the Adafruit libraries were too large, so they all got switched out for more concise, compact libraries that fit my purposes